# Play discord command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I have been having a problem with a play command with discord. I am unsure of what the problem is and if it is possible please help. I will be honest I got this code from somewhere else but its for a private server. Please help fix this thank you. Anyway I have been trying to create a play, stop, skip, nowplaying command for ages and if this works it would be amazing thank you.

Console Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Code:

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  description: "Play a song in your channel!",
  async execute(message) {
    try {
      const args = message.content.split(" ");
      const queue = message.client.queue;
      const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);

      const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
      if (!voiceChannel)
        return message.channel.send(
          "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
        );
      const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
      if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
        return message.channel.send(
          "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
        );
      }

      const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
      const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
      };

      if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
          textChannel: message.channel,
          voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
          connection: null,
          songs: [],
          volume: 5,
          playing: true
        };

        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

        queueContruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
          var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
          queueContruct.connection = connection;
          this.play(message, queueContruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          queue.delete(message.guild.id);
          return message.channel.send(err);
        }
      } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        return message.channel.send(
          `${song.title} has been added to the queue!`
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send(error.message);
    }
  },

  play(message, song) {
    const queue = message.client.queue;
    const guild = message.guild;
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if (!song) {
      serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
      queue.delete(guild.id);
      return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
      .play(ytdl(song.url))
      .on("finish", () => {
        serverQueue.songs.shift();
        this.play(message, serverQueue.songs[0]);
      })
      .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thats probably because `message.client.queue` does not exist as you can see from the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client). Thats why your `queue` variable is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You should look where you got the code from, maybe you missed a part?
specifically where they define `client.queue`
usually most of the people define it like

```
client.queue = new Map()
```

or [discord.js collection class](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods) (Extended from map)

in your main bot file (index.js, bot.js etc).

You could either check where you got code from or try adding this to where you define client in your main bot file